# How do I move a column in an Excel Online Survey Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

In Excel On-line (Office 365), how do I move a column in a table

(I don't just mean move a regular column, I mean a Table Column the type of table you get when you click Insert-table)

I have a Survey which I've added a field/question to but I would like to re-position it closer to the beginning of the table instead of adding it to the end.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried cut and paste?

Comment: Yes but it just inserts a column and leaves a renamed column in its place where the survey puts the info

Answer (score -1):

Select the table till the data is entered or till the column has a table format and not the whole column. Then put your cursor between the two columns of your first cell for which column you want to move. You should see dark black 4 arrows. Click and move where you want to.